# Angularjs ng-repeat item for tag attributes

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My question is how can I use `item` from `ng-repeat` on the same tag I am declaring `ng-repeat`

What I need (in some abstract template language):

```
{% for item in items %}
     <li data-theme="{{ item.dataTheme }}">{{ item.name }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

With angular I do not know how to access that `item.dataTheme`

```
<li data-theme="{{ item.dataTheme }}" ng-repeat="item in items">{{ item.name }}</li>
```

Comment: your code should work fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/FMK3s/1/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use

```
<li data-theme="{{ item.dataTheme }}" ng-repeat="item in items">{{ item.name }}</li>
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/FMK3s/)

Comment: Wow that is straightforward....:) I guess I was trying to do `<li {{ item.dataTheme }} ...</li>` to insert raw html... and that didnt work out. Thanks for answer.

Comment: how it's differs with posted one? Or OP edit own question with answer?

Comment: It sounds like the OP tried some code that failed, but when he wrote the question he wrote different - and correct! - code, which is pretty amazing.