# Preselect <option> in <select> while using ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am using AngularJS and HTML. Is there a way to pre-select an option in an option tag if my options are being generated using an ng-repeat? See below code snippet for example:

**HTML:**

```
<select class="form-control" id="eventSelectMenu">
    <option ng-repeat="option in allEventData">{{option.name}}</option>
</select>
```

I have tried solutions presented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106473/how-to-preselect-option-in-select-box-using-jquery) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3518002/how-can-i-set-the-default-value-for-an-html-select-element), but none have been successful.

Thank you for any advice you can give!

Comment: Is using ng-repeat a requirement?  Typically using a [select directive with ngOptions](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select) is better for select elements in angular

Comment: In addition to what Dustin said, you are not assigning a `value` to any of your options and you do not have an `ng-model` on your `<select>`. Are you mixing this with jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can set any item which should be pre-selected as value of select's `ngModel`

```js
console.clear();
angular.module('so-answer', [])
  .controller('ctrl', ['$scope',
    function($scope) {
      $scope.options = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
      $scope.selected = 3;
    }
  ])
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="so-answer" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <select ng-model="selected" ng-options="opt for opt in options"></select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this syntax. Also, you need to use the ng-model that will five you the value you need to select:

```
<select class="form-control"
        ng-model="yourmodel"
        ng-options="option for option in allEventData">
     </select>
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answers already posted, I'll add this one.  This one demonstrates how to use an array of objects for the select.  In this case the events in allEventData are assumed to have a `name` and `value` property.  Adjust to your case accordingly

```js
angular.module("app", [])
.controller("controller", function($scope){
  $scope.allEventData = [
    {
      value: 1,
      name: "Event 1"
    },
    {
      value: 2,
      name: "Event 2"
    },
    {
      value: 3,
      name: "Event 3"
    }
  ]
  
  $scope.selectedEventValue = 3
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app" ng-controller="controller">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angularjs@1.5.7" data-semver="1.5.7" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <select class="form-control" id="eventSelectMenu" ng-model="selectedEventValue" ng-options="item.value as item.name for item in allEventData">      
    </select>
    <pre>Selected Value: {{selectedEventValue}}</pre>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to bind attribute directly like

`<option ng-repeat="option in allEventData" selected={{option.selected}}>{{option.name}}</option>`

[similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18546994/angularjs-ng-repeat-item-for-tag-attributes)

Answer (score 1):

I like this:

```
<select id="test"
                    name="test"
                    ng-model="vm.form.existing"
                    ng-options="item.value as item.title for item in vm.existingData">
            </select>
```